# What would a "reset to factory settings" term be for a digital app?

Tags: terminology, applications, reset

I am developing an app in which I want to have a command to remove all user data and delete all preferences, bringing the state of the app back to the way it was the day it was downloaded. However, I'm having a hard time naming this command. (It would be accessed via a button in the preferences, but I'm not sure how the button should be labeled).

I've seen the term "Reset to factory defaults" used for certain specialty hardware (e.g. 3D printer, Kindle), which makes sense as it clearly indicates that the device would be reverting to the way it was set up when it was in a factory, which was before the user received it. However, this doesn't seem appropriate for a digital app that was never from a factory.

So what would be an equivalent "reset to factory settings" term be for a digital app? It would of course still need to be recognizable as a total reset command and fairly short. If there are any examples of apps using such a term, that would be even better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've seen so far,

1. Restore Defaults
2. Restore Default Settings
3. Reset App Settings
4. Reset All Settings

Followed by a confirmation dialogue informing the user that all his/her saved settings will be lost and the application will be rolled back to its original state.

[image]

Comment: I find it interesting that in the example of the followup message that it still says "factory-default values". Was this for a digital app or boxed software? Perhaps this is still an appropriate term to use.